# Firefox won't access my webcam in Google Meet; will access it for other sites

Tags: firefox, webcam

I have two webcams: One built into my laptop, and an external one attached over USB. When I go to meet.google.com, Firefox only allows me to access the internal webcam. When I go to other sites, Firefox gives me the choice of both cameras. How can I use my external webcam with meet.google.com?

My external webcam used to work with meet.google.com. It stopped working about a week ago —- I'm not sure if Firefox updated around that time.

This is the permissions box I get on meet.google.com. Only the internal camera is listed.

[image: google meet permissions]

But on onlinemictest.com, Firefox lists both cameras:

[image]

Here are the things I've tried:

- Cleared cookies and site data
- Went to Preferences -> Privacy and Security -> Permissions -> Camera, and removed meet.google.com, to force it to ask for permission again.
- Rebooted
- Checked the Security and Privacy system preferences

I'm running macOS 10.14.6 and Firefox 76.0.1

Comment: Logitech webcams never used to work at all in that type of situation, though they apparently fixed it more recently. Do you have the latest Logitech CP/drivers installed?

Comment: You can always check to see when Firefox (or any app for that matter) released an update by looking at their "releases" page For Firefox:  https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/  But, generally speaking, it's unlikely to be a Firefox issue since it works in Firefox in *other* websites.  The one thing that could make it a Firefox issue is a permissions thing for that particular website.  See:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-manage-your-camera-and-microphone-permissions

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Google Meet is choosing camera using it's own form, unlike the other websites (i.e. mentioned onlinemictest.com).

To access this form from the lobby:

1. click on the **"three dots button" (⋮)**
2. choose **"Settings"**
3. select **"Video" tab**
4. you should be able to **select different WebCam**, i.e. your Logitech USB WebCam

Comment: Wow, this is so unintuitive! The Firefox GUI gave me a list of two cameras to choose from, which implies that Firefox is responsible for picking which camera to show google, so I never would have expected the selection to be in google's settings. The list excluded the camera I care about, so I assumed Firefox couldn't even detect it. Never would have guessed I needed to tell the website to tell the browser about the hardware.

Comment: Thank you!! An easy and bizarre answer to a very frustrating problem..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Meet didn't start at all, despite the camera and audio were authorised. Then, I saw the problem in the console: I have a plug-in against WebRTC (ie, against spying sites that track people via browser, even when they use a VPN) and Meet started working after disabling it.